# Find two strings in parent string

Tags: python, string

i have a problem with my homework.

The task is you have a parent string, example `s = "stopgame"` and two other strings, that mean to be in the parent string, example `sub1 = "sam"` and `sub2 = "topge"`. Need to edit parent string like `"StopgAMe"`, meaning one of substrings should be written in uppercase inside parent string.
This is the one of the variants, i solved it, with a simple code like:

```
# "stopgame", "sam", "topge"
s, sub1, sub2 = str(input()), str(input()), str(input())
for i in s:
    for j in sub1:
        if j == i:
            s = s.replace(i, j.upper(), 1)
print(s)
# > "StopgAMe"

# counts the number of UC-LC LC-UC connections
counter = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i + 1 >= len(s):
        break
    if (s[i].islower() and s[i+1].isupper()) or (s[i].isupper() and s[i+1].islower()):
        counter += 1
    else:
        continue
print(counter)
```

But other variants contains an odd input like `s = "ababbaba", sub1 = "abbb", sub2 = "abaa"` and edited string should look like this `"abABBaBa"`
Tried to do this with string slices but unsuccessful.

***Edit #1***: Output must be a number of points were lowercase connects to uppercase and upper connects to lower, like "Sa" "gA" "Me" in "StopgAMe" = 3, this part is works properly. I have an issue with strings that aren't words at all, just set of letters

***Edit #2***: Using python libraries is not allowed.

Comment: Does every run have two outputs? Or can you choose, which substring you want to take?

Comment: @eDonkey no, output must be a number of points were lowercase connects to uppercase and upper connects to lower, like "Sa" "gA" "Me" in "StopgAMe", this part is working properly. I have an issue with strings that aren't words at all, just set of letters

Comment: I am still confused.. so there must (only) be a UC-LC LC-UC connection, but when i look at the expected output `abABBaBA`, wouldnt that be a LC-UC **UC-UC** UC-LC conection? Maybe you can post the task you received.